# How loading RDD works in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I'm new to Spark and have a question regarding the RDD. Let's say I define an RDD as follows:

```
val data1 = sc.textFile()
```

and then let's say I do the following

```
1) val data2 = data1.map{...}
2) val data3 = data1
```

I'm curious to know what happens behind the scene in 1 and 2. Are `data1`,`data2` and `data3` are totally different in memory? That is, does each of them take some piece of memory or there is some level of data sharing? For example, there is just one piece of memory for `data1` and `data3` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RDD`'s are merely representations of the work to be done, known as the lineage. And, that is "immutable"*, which leads me to the first scenario. `data1` is an instruction to load a file. When you use it's `map` method, that composes that instruction with the new one so that it returns a new instruction set which is `load file then transform it`. So, it is a new instruction set containing the first. In the second scenario, you end up with two memory locations that point to the same instructions.

So, really, ALL of those scenarios have the same instruction set. You can see that in the following code:

```
val init = sc.parallelize(1 to 10).map(x=>{println(x);x})
val mapped = init.map(_+1)
val initCopy = init
initCopy.cache
initCopy.collect //Notice that the println occurs...this also caches the end result
mapped.collect //Notice that the println does NOT occur since it was using the same instruction that was cached
```

*I say this in quotes because pieces of it can be modified, like when you call `cache`, but the lineage is immutable.

Comment: so for the second instruction (val data3=data1) when I run an action on  data1, it brings the data into memory and execute the instruction on it. and then if I execute a different action on data3, it brings the data into memory again and execute the new instruction? Is that right?

If that is correct, what is I have .cache() fro the data1?

Comment: That is right, it will constantly load (granted parallelize memoizes the data on first call...but most other loads are all the time) If you have data1 cached and call data3.collect, you'll be pulling from the cache.